# Input type = radio, can select multiple answers?

Tags: html

Good day, before we start, forgive the noobishness of the question. Just picked up HTML today.

I'm experimenting with the following code:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" id="radeng" checked />Male
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="radnor" />Female
</form>
```

Now, the way I understood it, I should be able to pick either "Male" or "Female" from the first selection.

Problem is, I can select both "Male" AND "Female".

Which is a little weird, and kinda' goes against what I'm trying to achieve.

Can anyone spot my error?

Comment: Your inputs need name attributes that are the same. i.e. `name="gender"`.

Comment: Ah that explains it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**17 Forms / 17.2.1 Control types**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1)
>
> Radio buttons are like checkboxes except that when **several share the same control name, they are mutually exclusive**: when one is switched "on", all others with the same name are switched "off".

Therefore if you want the radio elements to be mutually exclusive, you need to give them all the same `name` attribute. In this case, I gave them both a value of `gender`.

For usability, I'd also suggest wrapping the text nodes with `label` elements with `for` attributes that match the radio element `id`s. In doing so, you can toggle the radios by clicking the text (label).

```html
<form>
  <label for="radeng">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radeng" checked />

  <label for="radnor">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radnor" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a `name` attribute with the same value and it will select only one. Also, you should use `<label>` tag for specifying the names of your checkboxes.

Lets have some clean markup :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="radeng">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radeng" name="gender" checked />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="radnor">Female</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radnor" name="gender" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/743gmwa3/)

So by specifying same values for `name` attribute groups your radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Give same name for the both radio button like below:

```
<form>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radeng" checked />Male
<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radnor" />Female
</form>
```